# how to use appearance to display a menulist-button in IE?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

How to use appearance to display a menulist-button in IE?

```
.selectize-input::after {
/*appearance:menulist-button;*/
  -webkit-appearance: menulist-button;
  -moz-appearance: menulist-button;
}
```

Chrome:

[image]

IE:

[image]

arrow icon  is not coming in IE.
Here I want to write same class for IE 9, 10, 11
I tried to give

```
appearance:menulist-button;
```

But it is not working.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appearance is not supported for IE. Check out the CanIuse website: http://caniuse.com/#search=appearance

You would have to write an IE specific work around. To be honest I'd abandon appearance and look for a solution thats better supported like a jQuery navigation: https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

There are lots of this type of pattern out there that have tried and tested multi browser support. No need to reinvent the wheel :)